# Easy roots for constant plus factorized polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

I have a polynomial $p(x) = \prod_{j=1}^m (x-a_j)$. Now I make a new polynomial by adding a constant, $q(x) = p(x) + c$. Can I use my knowledge of the roots of $p(x)$ to make it easier to find the roots of $q(x)$?

Clarifications: The constants are real and I'm generally only interested in real roots. I apologize for the vague use of "easier". One definition would be be that you can write the new roots in terms of the old ones using elementary operations. [Milo Brandt](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1602752/292514) has shown that this not possible. On the other hand, in the comments, Travis points out that if $c$ is small, then the old roots will be good guesses for finding the new roots. With this in mind, I will define "easier" as follows. I could expand $q(x)$ and input it into a generic numerical root finding algorithm; is there a way to use knowledge of $p(x)$ to find roots faster or more accurately?

Comment: It depends on what you mean, but if $c$ is small in a suitable sense, the original roots $a_j$ are good candidates for seed values when applying Newton's Method to approximate the roots of $q(x)$.

Comment: Thanks! That's a good point. Sadly $c$ is large in my case.

Comment: If $p$ is real, when $|c|$ is large enough (or sometimes even when it is small when some root $a_j$ is repeated an even number of times) then $q$  will in general have fewer than $\deg q = m$ real roots. One can use the $a_j$ and $c$ to extract some conditions on the roots of $q$ using Rouche's Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem), but whether this is useful depends on what one means by "easier to find the roots". (In fact, this works for a general complex polynomial $\Bbb C$, in particular a real polynomial with some complex roots.)

Comment: If you are seeking real roots, then for $|c|$ large enough, $p(x) + c$ will have one or two or no roots!

Comment: This is another great point. In fact, we can easily calculate the sign over each interval for $p(x)$. If $c$ is positive, we can rule out certain intervals as potential roots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to find the roots of a shift of a polynomial from the roots of the polynomials itself using only radicals, addition, multiplication, and division. In particular, adding a constant to a polynomial, one can change a nice well behaved polynomial like:
$$x^5-x=0$$
which factors as
$$x(x-1)(x+1)(x-i)(x+i)$$
into a polynomial which has no solutions expressible in terms of radicals:
$$x^5-x+1=0.$$
This is a problem, as it rules out there being any "easy" formula relating the roots of a polynomial to the roots of a translate.